# Divide objects between arrays with constraints

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, set

Let's say we have a set of objects a1, a2, ... an

And we have empty arrays g1, g2, ...gm each of which can possibly include only some of the objects and has to contain a specific number of objects, for example:

- g1 can include [a1,a5,a8] has to contain 2 objects
- g2 can include [a5,a6,a7,a9,a10] has to contain 3 objects
- ...
- gm can include [a1,a6,a8,a10] has to contain 4 objects

What is the best algorithm to check whether it is possible to distribute objects between arrays (it is not necessary to use all of the objects) with the above-mentioned constraints and to get that distribution if possible?

Comment: Is their a guarantee that sum of objects which  (g1,..gm) has to contain = n?

Comment: @marvel308 no. I've edited the question

Comment: it would be invalid if gi does not contain the desired number of ai in it right ?

Comment: @marvel308 right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a flow problem How

1. Suppose we have a Source S which has an edge to each Ai with capacity = 1
2. There is an edge from Ai to Gj if Gj can include Ai. The capacity would be equal to 1
3. Their is an edge from each Gj to Sink with capacity equal to the value which it must have.
4. Now if we run max flow, each Ai would get mapped to a Gj. The total flow should be equal to the sum of weights from Gj to sink.
5. If the sum is valid, then just get the mappings in the flow. else it is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Let **n** be the total number of objects and **m** be the total number of arrays.

```
x=n;
y=m+1;
arangement_possible=true;
while(y>=2)
{
   if(x<=0)
   {
      arrangement_possible = false;
      break;
    }
   x=x-y;
   y=y-1;
 }
```

if the arrangement_possible is true then such arrangement is possible else not.

or

chk for this condition

(((m(m+1))/2)-1) <= n

Comment: your algorithm doesn't satisfy the constraints for arrays (about the objects they can have), for example g1 can include ONLY [a1,a5,a8]

Comment: okay so u want to chk that then u need to loop through each array to find it then.

Comment: That 's not a solution. Check marvel308's answer